# Split PDF after RegEx: Where should I start?

Tags: java, php, python, regex, pdf

I am trying to split gargantuan PDFs based on a RegEx of the sort

[A-Z][a-z]+(\s–\s)[A-Z][a-z]+

Because after every instance of this begins a new 'section' that I need to be split into its own document.

I have no idea where to begin, or what language to look at first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd be better of using a library to split PDFs as the proprietary structure of a PDF is too complex to be split by a regex.

Comment: Not a chance.  PDFs contain compressed data in any of a number of different formats.  Searching the PDF file for a regex directly is The Wrong Way.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a PDF at the byte stream level will not result in a valid PDF.

Now that we've got that out of the way, you'll need a library (Apache PDFBox in java, pyPDF in python) that can parse PDFs and let you iterate over the text, applying your regexp. Once you've found the text you use the library to extract the relevant page ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the PDF Toolkit can help http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Answer (score 0):

A PDF contains alsorts of file structures, it is not just a collection of pages. So you can't just break it up.